# Image persisting in my database but not displaying on the frontend

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working on a project with Laravel 5.2. I need to create, edit and display user profile. The user profile should have an uploaded user image. Below is a code snippet from my controller. This is meant to persist the user photo, drop it in a file called images. The photos persists in the database, it doesn't drop in the images folder neither does it display on the front end.

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    /*   User::create($request->all());
       */

    $input=$request->all();
    $input['password']=bcrypt($request->password);

    if ($file=$request->file('photo_id')){

        $name= time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images',$name);
        $photo=Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id']=$photo->id;


    }

    User::create($input);
    return redirect('admin/users');

}
```

also this is my front end table to display the image.

```
 <tr>

       <td><a href="{{route('admin.users.edit', $user->id)}}">{{$user->name}}</a></td>
       <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
       <td><img height='50' src="/images/{{ isset($user->photo)?$user->photo['file']:"has no photo"}}" alt=""></td>
       <td>{{$user->is_active = 1 ? 'Active':'Non-Active' }}</td>
       <td>{{$user->role['name'] }}</td>
       <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
       <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

I need image to drop in the images folder, persist in the database and display on the front end. Any one please?

Comment: After upload profile image, image drops in image folder?? do check it?

Comment: Please check your image is properly stored in **images** folder

Comment: No it did not. but it dropped in my database.

Comment: Yes it is under my public folder, I just checked to be sure.

Comment: Does the path from the public folder match the path being generated on your page?

Comment: yes, it does. as you can see from my controller and my blade view I used the images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
<td><img height='50' src="/images/{{ isset($user->photo)?$user->photo['file']:"has no photo"}}" alt=""></td>
```

And use

```
<td><img height='50' src="{{ url('images/' . \App\Photo::find($user->photo_id)->file) }}" alt=""></td>
//Include valid Photo.php location that you create. I just use demo...
```